# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share() when use breadcrumbs package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Today, I want to use [Laravel Breadcrumbs](https://laravel-breadcrumbs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package with laravel **5.4**. I used that with laravel **5.3** without any problem and all things worked fine.

But when run the application I got this error :

```
FatalErrorException in ServiceProvider.php line 34:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()
```

I searched for that and I found that As of laravel 5.4 `share` has been removed. and I must to use the `singleton` instead.

But when I did that changes In the `ServiceProvider.php` like this :

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app['breadcrumbs'] = $this->app->singleton(function($app)
        {
            $breadcrumbs = $this->app->make('DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\Manager');

            $viewPath = __DIR__ . '/../views/';

            $this->loadViewsFrom($viewPath, 'breadcrumbs');
            $this->loadViewsFrom($viewPath, 'laravel-breadcrumbs'); // Backwards-compatibility with 2.x

            $breadcrumbs->setView($app['config']['breadcrumbs.view']);

            return $breadcrumbs;
        });
    }
```

I got another error. like this :

```
ErrorException in Container.php line 1057:
Illegal offset type in unset
```

I do not know what is problem. can anyone help me ?

**Update :**

I found the solution [Here](https://github.com/colinajd/laravel-breadcrumbs/commit/38784c78aa1b8b6d080fb52ab6bbb79cd03cd915).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that the singleton instance expects a class to bind to as the first argument, which in this case is `'breadcrumbs'`.

The second problem is that you don't need to explicitly declare the array key for the singleton instance. So this is how it should look:

```
$this->app->singleton('breadcrumbs', function($app)
```

The next problem is that the package you're using has been `abandoned`. The developer will no longer maintain it.

The final problem is that you're using a version `< 3.0.2`. So change the version in your `composer.json` to `3.0.2` and then install that, then you shouldn't need to be modifying any files.